# Spark consumer not receiving Kafka messages

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a Spark scala consumer that is connecting to my Kafka brokers on another cluster (Kafka cluster is separate from CDH cluster). `params` are my Kafka params that being picked up correctly.

```
val incomingstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext, .....](topicSet, params))
print(incomingstream)
```

I am able to produce and consume on the console of my Kafka cluster. But on running the spark consumer having the above code, it just keeps waiting and even though i send messages through the kafka console producer it doesnt show up on the log prints. `incomingstream` doesnt get printed.

I have connectivity from the node where spark job is running to kafka cluster. Submitting in yarn mode. Shows connection to kafka brokers. (Not sure if the issue is because of Kerberos...doesnt say that in logs..)

Using CDH 5.10

Spark 2.2

Kafka 0.10

Scala 2.11.8

EDIT: Kafka Params passed in as below. Connecting fine to my kafka brokers from the spark job - printed the logs

```
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "<domain>:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean),
    "security.protocol" -> "PLAINTEXT"
```

My Kafka listener is configured as plaintext (not SSL) - but if i pass the above, It is complaining of

```
Selector:375 - Connection with 10.18.63.18 disconnected
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:83)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
```

Comment: What are the params you passed in?

Comment: Added more details abt params and exception

Comment: Try to set auto.offset.reset to earliest to see if it helps. If set it as latest, it means it will only consume messages sent to the broker AFTER the spark streaming job is running.

Comment: I did that, I see the following errors in Kafka logs dir in zookeeper.out
WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
INFO Closed socket connection for client /16.87.12.125:4782 (no session established for client) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.       NIOServerCnxn)